# jQuery: question about autocomplete and keys

Tags: jquery, key, jquery-autocomplete

I have a multiple select and an autocomplete input. Each time the user insert an element in the autocomplete input I would like to select the corresponding element in the multiple select.

I have this code:

```
jQuery("#example")
.autocomplete('autocomplete', jQuery.extend({}, {
dataType: 'json',
parse: function(data) {

  var parsed = [];
  for (key in data) {

     parsed[parsed.length] = { data: [ data[key], key ], value: data[key], result: data[key] };
  }

  return parsed;

  }
}, {multiple:true}))
.result(function(event, data) {
 $("#select option[value=" + key + "]").attr("selected", true);


});
```

The action autocomplete is returning this kind of data:

```
{"17":"element_17","18":"element_18"}
```

The problem: the value of "key" `(value=" + key + ")` is always 18, even when i select element_17.

Any idea what should i change/add?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what is going on, is you are formating your data incorrectly for your auto complete.

you want each auto-complete element to look like

```
{ 'key' : '17', 'value' : 'element 17' }
```

And you would need to send down an array of elements that looks like this

```
[ { 'key' : '17', 'value' : 'element 17' },
  { 'key' : '18', 'value' : 'element 18' } ]
```

Comment: Do you mean { 'key' : '17', 'value' : 'element 17' },
  { 'key' : '18', 'value' : 'element 18' } (without "[" and "]")?

Comment: no, i mean that with the [], that is the way arrays are implemented in JSON

Comment: I have now in the Firebug Response tab exactly what you say and in the JSON tab i have this: 0
Object {key="17", value="element 17"}
key
"17"
value
"element 17"
1
Object {key="18", value="element 18"}
key
"18"
value
"element 18". But when I write "el" ("element") doesn't appear "element 18" nor "element 17"..